# error: no such module 'Solana' in build archive section ( GitHub CICD )

Tags: xcode, github-actions, swift5, cicd

I am using [Solana](https://github.com/ajamaica/Solana.Swift) Swift Package Dependency in my project and created the custom classes to use the features, imported the Solana module in those classes. But while running the CICD work flow ( GitHub actions ) in the build archive option getting the error **error: no such module 'Solana'** in the custom classes. I have also attached the screenshot regarding that. (It's working in manual archive from Xcode.)

I have also added clean and build command in the CICD workflow so can fetch this Package Dependency. I am fixing this error since many days but not getting success so please I would like your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your action yaml file to check further.

Comment: @Sam-Sundar Please find it here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WW4cfN4T1b7ZMljOokK_zh6SzItRfzsI/view?usp=sharing  Thanks

Comment: able to solve the issue ? @Nikunj5294